# How to get autogenerated column's width from code behind at runtime (dataGrid)

Tags: c#, wpf

In Winforms there was a simple dataGridView.Columns[0].Width, but how to do it in WPF?

When debugging I see this in every column

[image]

which is totally untrue, because my columns are a lot wider than 20 (pixels, I assume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the ActualWidth which is the actual measured width of the column. Usually Width is more of a preference rather than a hard value.

Comment: I think you need to post that code that gets you that output, because I have just checked on a datagrid and the actualwidth columns are all set correctly for me

Answer (score 0):

Since the columns are autogenerated,in the AutoGeneratedColumns event of dataGrid

```
 TestDataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += (s, e) =>
                     {
                       if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "YourColumnName")
                         e.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(1,
                                           DataGridLengthUnitType.
                                             Star);
                     };
```

Comment: Ok, but this code will SET the width, and I want to GET it. Besides, '*' will make them spread evenly across dataGrid and I can't interfere with that. Correct me if I'm wrong